# How can I install a package with go get?

Tags: go, go-toolchain

I want to install packages from github to my `$GOPATH`, I have tried this:

```
go get github.com:capotej/groupcache-db-experiment.git
```

the repository is [here](https://github.com/capotej/groupcache-db-experiment).

Comment: See also [Where does go get install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633092/where-does-go-get-install-packages)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

> [Command go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/)
>
> [Download and install packages and dependencies](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go get [-d] [-f] [-t] [-u] [-v] [-fix] [-insecure] [build flags] [packages]
> ```
>
> Get downloads the packages named by the import paths, along with their
>   dependencies. It then installs the named packages, like 'go install'.
>
> The -d flag instructs get to stop after downloading the packages; that
>   is, it instructs get not to install the packages.
>
> The -f flag, valid only when -u is set, forces get -u not to verify
>   that each package has been checked out from the source control
>   repository implied by its import path. This can be useful if the
>   source is a local fork of the original.
>
> The -fix flag instructs get to run the fix tool on the downloaded
>   packages before resolving dependencies or building the code.
>
> The -insecure flag permits fetching from repositories and resolving
>   custom domains using insecure schemes such as HTTP. Use with caution.
>
> The -t flag instructs get to also download the packages required to
>   build the tests for the specified packages.
>
> The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named
>   packages and their dependencies. By default, get uses the network to
>   check out missing packages but does not use it to look for updates to
>   existing packages.
>
> The -v flag enables verbose progress and debug output.
>
> Get also accepts build flags to control the installation. See 'go help
>   build'.
>
> When checking out a new package, get creates the target directory
>   GOPATH/src/. If the GOPATH contains multiple entries, get
>   uses the first one. For more details see: 'go help gopath'.
>
> When checking out or updating a package, get looks for a branch or tag
>   that matches the locally installed version of Go. The most important
>   rule is that if the local installation is running version "go1", get
>   searches for a branch or tag named "go1". If no such version exists it
>   retrieves the default branch of the package.
>
> When go get checks out or updates a Git repository, it also updates
>   any git submodules referenced by the repository.
>
> Get never checks out or updates code stored in vendor directories.
>
> For more about specifying packages, see 'go help packages'.
>
> For more about how 'go get' finds source code to download, see 'go
>   help importpath'.
>
> This text describes the behavior of get when using GOPATH to manage
>   source code and dependencies. If instead the go command is running in
>   module-aware mode, the details of get's flags and effects change, as
>   does 'go help get'. See 'go help modules' and 'go help module-get'.
>
> See also: go build, go install, go clean.

---

For example, showing verbose output,

```
$ go get -v github.com/capotej/groupcache-db-experiment/...
github.com/capotej/groupcache-db-experiment (download)
github.com/golang/groupcache (download)
github.com/golang/protobuf (download)
github.com/capotej/groupcache-db-experiment/api
github.com/capotej/groupcache-db-experiment/client
github.com/capotej/groupcache-db-experiment/slowdb
github.com/golang/groupcache/consistenthash
github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
github.com/golang/groupcache/lru
github.com/capotej/groupcache-db-experiment/dbserver
github.com/capotej/groupcache-db-experiment/cli
github.com/golang/groupcache/singleflight
github.com/golang/groupcache/groupcachepb
github.com/golang/groupcache
github.com/capotej/groupcache-db-experiment/frontend
$
```

Comment: If this helps anyone, the solution to my problem (`package github.com/coreos/go-iptables.git: invalid version control suffix in github.com/ path`) was to remove the `.git` suffix from the Github URL.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith If you have `$GOPATH/bin` in your system path then you can run the program by binary name right away.  The `go get` command will generally build the code and (if it's a program) put the binary in the bin, so you can access right away in the terminal

Answer (score 127):

**First, we need GOPATH**

The `$GOPATH` is a folder (or set of folders) specified by its environment variable. We must notice that this is not the `$GOROOT` directory where Go is installed.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/gocode
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

We used `~/gocode` path in our computer to store the source of our application and its dependencies. The `GOPATH` directory will also store the binaries of their packages.

**Then check Go env**

You system must have `$GOPATH` and `$GOROOT`, below is my Env:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/elpsstu/gocode"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/pravin/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/pravin/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

**Now, you run download go package:**

```
go get [-d] [-f] [-fix] [-t] [-u] [build flags] [packages]
```

Get downloads and installs the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies. For more details you can look [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies).

Comment: Starting with Go v1.8, `GOPATH` defaults to `$HOME/go` if not set.  Source [1](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#gopath), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36083961/3998252).

Comment: the default `GOROOT` on Ubuntu18.04 is `GOROOT="/usr/local/go"`

Answer (score 96):

Note that since Go 1.17 installing packages with `go get` is [deprecated](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them):

> Building and installing packages with get is deprecated. In a future release, the `-d` flag will be enabled by default, and `go get` will be only be used to adjust dependencies of the current module. To install a package using dependencies from the current module, use `go install`.

This "future release" is Go 1.18, as mentioned [in the release notes](https://go.dev/doc/go1.18#go-command):

> `go get` no longer builds or installs packages in module-aware mode. `go get` is now dedicated to adjusting dependencies in go.mod. Effectively, the `-d` flag is always enabled.

(The `-d` flag instructs `go get` to only download packages and not install them.)

Use [`go install`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-install) instead:

> ```bash
> # Install the latest version of a program,
> # ignoring go.mod in the current directory (if any). 
> $ go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
>
> # Install a specific version of a program. 
> $ go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@v0.6.4
>
> # Install a program at the version selected by the module in the current directory. 
> $ go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls
>
> # Install all programs in a directory. 
> $ go install ./cmd/...
> ```

To install any other package, simply:

```
go install <package_name>@<version>
```

(you may omit the version suffix `@<version>`, e.g. `@latest`)

---

The Go 1.18 release notes also mention that `go get` will work as before with `GO111MODULE=off`. However in 2022 you should definitely migrate to modules and use `go install` instead.

Comment: And how to use go install with github? Please give an example too.

Comment: I try to install gophernotes. `go install github.com/gopherdata/gophernotes@latest` works OK.