# Error "command not found" after installing go-eval

Tags: macos, go

I'm trying to run `Go` in an interactive mode.

I want to use [`go-eval`](https://github.com/sbinet/go-eval/) for that, I followed their `README` instructions:

- I ran `go get github.com/sbinet/go-eval/` successfully
- I ran `go-eval` which resulted in `-bash: go-eval: command not found`

Some more information:

- `echo $PATH` returns: `/usr/local/go/bin:...`
- `echo $GOPATH` returns: `$HOME/golang`
- running `whereis go-eval` returns no output
- running `go install go-eval` returns:

  `can't load package: package go-eval: cannot find package "go-eval" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/go-eval (from $GOROOT)
    $HOME/golang/src/go-eval (from $GOPATH)`

Comment: What is your GOPATH? is GOPATH/bin in your PATH?

Comment: is $HOME/go/bin in your PATH?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You'll need to add `GOPATH/bin` to `PATH`.

```
PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
```

**Update** [[Go 1.8 and above]](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#gopath): `GOPATH` will default to `$HOME/go`. The above **will not work** if `GOPATH` is not explicitly set.

To set both, add this to your `.profile` file:

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Works. You **literally** need to use "$GOPATH" in the command to get a working setup. If you just manually write the full path, even if valid and accurate, it doesn't seem to work. Ultimately, when you test with "echo $PATH", all you'll see is just the path. The $GOPATH is used as a pointer to your environment variable, but that isn't indicated in any way when you test with "echo $PATH".

Comment: It should work if you manually enter the path, $GOPATH is just nicer because you don't have to hardcode the path (assuming GOPATH is set, which is no longer required starting with Go 1.8).

Comment: Update ~/.zshrc if you are using Iterm terminal

Answer (score 12):

1. add those line in to `~/.zshrc`

   ```bash
   export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
   export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
   ```
2. run `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 6):

Is the binary `go-eval` in `$GOPATH/bin`? Are you running the command with `$GOPATH/bin/` as your working directory? If not, thats likely the problem.

`go get` & `go install` installs go binaries (if any) in `$GOPATH/bin`

Check `$GOPATH/bin` for the go-eval binary. If its there, try running it from `$GOPATH/bin` with `./go-eval`. If that works, you're good.

In future, if you wish to run go binaries found in `$GOPATH/bin` from anywhere in your shell, add the following to your .bashrc or profile:

`export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`

Then restart your terminal or run `. ~/.bashrc` or `. /etc/profile`

> When running go install go-eval I get:
>
> can't load package: package go-eval: cannot find package "go-eval" in any of:
>      /usr/local/go/src/go-eval (from $GOROOT)
>      $HOME/golang/src/go-eval (from $GOPATH)

You get the above error because go-eval is not in `$HOME/golang/src/go-eval`. Running `go get github.com/sbinet/go-eval/` will download the source to `$GOPATH/src/github/sbinet/go-eval/`. If you want to run `go install go-eval`, you have to specify the package name relevant to its position in the directory hierarchy in `$GOPATH/src`.

e.g.
`go install github/sbinet/go-eval`

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this issue while using `export PATH="~/go/bin:$PATH"`.

Seems the `~` was causing problems and changing to the full path worked.

Try something like this instead, which won't use a tilde:

`export PATH="$HOME/go/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: The tilde doesn't expand when quoted, but without double quotes, it would work.

Comment: Yeah, just weird because I was under the impression that tilde's worked in the path. Guess not though.

Ironically I also happened to be under the impression tilde's did expand with double quotes as well for a while.. maybe it was just the shell/config I was using at the time though.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add this in addition to the answers given.

As a helpful tip, uou can always test your commands with the **which** command.

Such as:  **which go**

If the command is not found, you know you have a PATH problem you need to address first.

Then you can focus on finding the command with the **find** command.

Such as: **find / -name "go" -print 2>/dev/null**

The first slash is the directory to start the search, the argument to the -name is the command you're looking for and the -print gets a good results look. the 2>/dev/null sends results of directories that are not accessible to neverland (null) so that you do not need to see a bunch of errors.

Using this process helps you quickly find the command in question and then you can add it to your PATH env variable and it becomes accessible as stated in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

All above answers are self explaining. Over and above those I would like to add that by default you can access only those commands from terminal without path to binary whose `bin` folder is added to the environment variable, be it linux, mac or windows.

Else you will have to specify the path to bin folder of that software followed by the binary name. For instance in your case `<path_to_bin_folder>/go-eval`.

This is the most common reason that you are not able to execute that command directly from the command line. Please remember this and try this before searching for answers online because this will most probably solve your issue. All you have to know is the installation path.

So, write the following into the `rc` or `profile` file for your terminal and save, example for zsh it is `~/.zshrc`, for bash it is `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_rc`.

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Now although the file is saved but the changes will not reflect immediately. You have to source the profile file as mentioned above. For this type `source ~/.zshrc`. You should now be able to run the command directly from command line now. Even if the problem still persists try quit the terminal session and logging off and then logging in.

In case you want to add path to bin folder for other packages, you can append it to the $PATH environment variable using `:`. So for example if you want to add path to java binary as well, then just do

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Also it is a good practice to define the path to root folder of a package in its separate environment variable(example `$GOPATH="$HOME/go"`). In case if the installation path changes in future then you'll just have to update the environment variable related to that binary (example just update, $GOPATH="newpath") and your command will work as previously, since the change in $GOPATH will reflect in $PATH.