# How to fix ‘--go_out: protoc-gen-go: The system cannot find the file specified.’ error

Tags: windows, go, protocol-buffers

I Create a person.proto and I wanna compile this file to *.go .
I installed Package

> go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go

After executing the following command

> .\protoc.exe --go_out=. person.proto

I get the error below

> --go_out: protoc-gen-go: The system cannot find the file specified.

I want to use the buffer protocol, version 2

How can I fix this error?

My proto file:

```golang
package communication;

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/36083542/13860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Description

Unfortunately, it is said that none of the core developers develop on Windows, hence I solve the problem and add this answer for Windows developers.

However, the [possible duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36083542/13860) that @Flimzy mentioned doesn't work and I have done all the 6 steps below then surprisingly the problem has solved by step 7. Moreover, by mistake, I was running the command on a VSCode terminal.

---

### Procedure

1. Download `protoc-win32.zip` from "https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads".
2. Unzip the file then add the location of the `protoc.exe` to your PATH environment variable. In addition, it's not that much necessary, you can copy the `protoc.exe` to the `GOPATH`.
3. Change/Navigate the CMD/Powershell path to the file then run `protoc.exe --version` from the command prompt to verify the procedure.
4. Verify that your `GOPATH` environment variable is set.
5. Run `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go` from the CMD/Powershell. This should install the binary to `%GOPATH%/bin`.
6. Add the exact `%GOPATH%/bin` to your PATH environment variable.
7. Open a new CMD/Powershell, navigate to your `.proto` file then run `protoc --go_out=. *.proto`

---

***References:***

1. [How to install protoc-gen-go (Go protocol buffer compiler plugin) in windows?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Qs8d56uavVs)
2. [protoc-gen-go: protoc fails to compile in Windows](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/811)

Answer (score 5):

On windows, I ran the following command to resolve the issue.

`go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest`

`go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest`

[go-zero](https://go-zero.dev/docs/prepare/protoc-install/)

[Google developer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package)