# Go Binary Installed Through "Go Install" command outputs nothing

Tags: go, kubernetes

## Context:

[This](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/compile-install) go tutorial on building and installing Go binaries is what I followed. Until this one, I believe I've correctly followed every tutorial that comes before.

Here's a look at the basic main package that I wrote that calls packages from then neighboring directories.

[image]

As instructed in that tutorial, I also added to the PATH variable, my go binary output path:

`/home/exampleuser/go/bin`

Again, as instructed, I cd'd to my go main package directory and ran the following commands:

```
$ go build
$ go install
```

And as said in the documentation this did put the binary in the $GOBIN path which again has been added to the path variable:

## Expectation:

If `./caller` is the binary, after installing it, from any directory I should get the response as obtained by running the .go file with `go run`:

```
$ caller

>> map[SysAdmin:Great to see you, SysAdmin! CloudBender:Hail CloudBender, well met! Engineer:Hail Engineer, well met!]
```

## Actual Output:

```
$ caller

>>
```

**PS**

I am not sure if all the environment variables seen on running the `go env` command, are supposed to be printed out when echoed like: `echo $<GO ENV VARIABLE>`. For example when I tried echoing $GOBIN, I get a blank output.

Comment: As you mentioned, when the $GOBIN env is empty, you have some issues with your environment variables. Please provide the ``go env`` result then we can help you more.

Comment: Since the output is different you must be calling a different binary, so look at the individual path of the binary which the shell is calling from its PATH.

Comment: @TiGo Maybe that's the case. I tried setting the env variables a bit differently and then it worked.

Comment: `caller` might be a shell builtin. Your problem has nothing to do with Go. Don't name your stuff like OS or shell builtins.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083542/error-command-not-found-after-installing-go-eval). As said there, I tried setting $GOPATH first and then referenced it in $PATH and also set $GOBIN. and implemented it all by sourcing ~/.bashrc.

Additionally, I changed my module name a bit and then built and installed it. And then it worked as expected.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work like a traditional forum. When adding more details to your question please do so by editting your question rather than adding an "Answer" to your question. [Please see the StackOverflow Tour.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).