# cannot find package "github.com/user../../" in golang while building

Tags: go, github, build, glide-golang

I am trying to build a project from github source code. I have found some source code importing a package something like below:

```
import (
    "os"

    "github.com/bivas/rivi/commands"
    "github.com/mitchellh/cli"
)
```

However, while building a project every time it throws an error:

```
user-MacBook-Pro:rivi user$ go build rivi.go
rivi.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/bivas/rivi/commands" in any of:
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.5/libexec/src/github.com/bivas/rivi/commands (from $GOROOT)
        ($GOPATH not set)
rivi.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/mitchellh/cli" in any of:
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.5/libexec/src/github.com/mitchellh/cli (from $GOROOT)
        ($GOPATH not set)
```

how to build this project. Currently I am trying to build this one [project](https://github.com/bivas/rivi) into my system.

***EDITED:***

After running this command `go install` or `go get`:

```
package github.com/bivas/rivi/commands: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/bivas/rivi/connectors/github: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/bivas/rivi/engine/actions/autoassign: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/bivas/rivi/engine/actions/automerge: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/bivas/rivi/engine/actions/commenter: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/bivas/rivi/engine/actions/labeler: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/bivas/rivi/engine/actions/locker: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/bivas/rivi/engine/actions/sizing: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/bivas/rivi/engine/actions/slack: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/bivas/rivi/engine/actions/status: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/bivas/rivi/engine/actions/trigger: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/mitchellh/cli: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

Comment: You need to pull the package's dependencies using `go install` or `go get` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295146/how-can-i-install-a-package-with-go-get). You may also want to go through the [getting started](https://golang.org/doc/install) page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install a package with go get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295146/how-can-i-install-a-package-with-go-get)

Comment: I tried running this but getting few errors, request you to go throught my updated questions

Comment: The output clearly tells you: "cannot download, $GOPATH not set.". Please read through the getting started page linked above.

Comment: You should also update to a current version of Go. GOPATH has a default setting now.

Answer (score 4):

This question is a few years old now. I was experiencing the same problem. The solution for me was that I needed to run `go mod init [name_of_main_go_file]`, which creates the go.mod file. Then you can run `go run .`

https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started#call

Comment: Thanks, I spent HOURS looking for the answer. This worked for me:
`go mod init mything.go` `go mod tidy` `go run mything.go`

Answer (score 0):

This problem common if you haven't setup any go path yet. It is necessary.

I am assuming from the command line snap of yours, that you are a UNIX user. Googles official doc recommend that you setup your go path manually . $GOROOT is optional but $GOPATH has to be set if you are trying to get third party libraries.

Edit your ~/.bash_profile to add the following line:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/work
```

Then logout and login or use `source ~/.bash_profile`
You can read more from [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH#unix-systems). Assuming your Golang package directory is in `work` folder inside your `home` directory. The directory structure of work folder has to look like this,

- work

  - src
  - pkg
  - bin