# Where does go get install packages?

Tags: go, homebrew

I've been given instructions to run `go get <some-remote-git-repo>` which seems to succeed, but it's not clear to me where the package was installed to so I can run an executable from it.

Per https://golang.org/doc/code.html#remote it seems it will be installed in `$GOPATH/bin` but `$GOPATH` isn't defined in my shell (though the `go get` command seems to work fine). Go is installed via Homebrew.

Comment: For those who find this question: note that installing with go get is deprecated. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68809471/4108803) for further info

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I found the missing clue by running `brew info go`, which says:

```
==> Caveats
A valid GOPATH is required to use the `go get` command.
If $GOPATH is not specified, $HOME/go will be used by default:
  https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH
```

From that I found the executable in question at `$HOME/go/bin`.

Comment: Just to add to this, this is not particular to homebrew but GO in general. You can also do `go env GOPATH` to check where your GOPATH is pointed to as mentioned in [this doc](https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code#GOPATH)

Answer (score 21):

```
go env
```

you can get the path from `GOMODCACHE`

Comment: I use this command to get the path: `go env | grep GOMODCACHE`

Answer (score 6):

Even if you don't have a $GOPATH variable you can see what it uses by doing `go env GOPATH`.

Try this to see what your path is:

```
echo `go env GOPATH`/bin
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem which is why I found your question.  However, in my case I did not have an empty GOPATH but one with multiple directories.  I worked out the issue and describe it here...

If you run go get and you already have the package it says nothing (even with the -v option).  This is confusing if it's not in the first directory of your GOPATH.  Ie you run go get , there is no error or any message but when you check the first directory of the GOPATH (which is where the doc says it should be) you can't find it.

I eventually found it, but since I have a large GOPATH this was rather tedious.

Comment: next time try `go get -u -x ...`

Comment: Do you mean `go get -u -v -x <packageName>` what does that do, how do I read the output?

Answer (score -3):

Using **go build**

```
go build
go mod init project_name
go mod tidy
```