# How to find a Go package installed with 'go get -u' when no $GOPATH is defined?

Tags: go, gopath

I'm following the gRPC Quickstart tutorial for Go, https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/go/, and have installed gRPC using the command

```
go get -u google.golang.org/grpc
```

I actually haven't defined a `GOPATH` environment variable:

```
> echo $GOPATH
```

which, as I understand it, means that it defaults to `~/go`, or in my case `/Users/kurt/go`.

At the next step, I'd like to build the example by doing

```
cd $GOPATH/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld
```

However, I find that the directory doesn't exist, and there is also no `google.golang.org` directory in `/Users/kurt/go/src`:

```
~/g/src> ls *google*
fish: No matches for wildcard '*google*'. See `help expand`.
ls *google*
   ^
```

Should the package not be located here? That's what I understand from [Where does go get install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633092/where-does-go-get-install-packages).

Comment: what about `ls -alh ~ && tree ~/go/` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Go Modules, you can find 'go get' downloaded files at:

```
~/go/pkg/mod/cache/download
```

However, it should be treated like an immutable copy of the source code.

If you want a mutable copy of the source code, you should clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example output, you are in ~/g/arc

Go path default would be ~/go/src

I think auto complete bit ya there

Comment: That's actually just the way the Fish shell abbreviates paths; if I `pwd` I get `/Users/kurt/go/src` which is the expected directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I worked around the problem by cloning https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go which appears to contain the `examples/helloworld` directory I'm looking for. Still curious to hear where the package downloaded with `go get` is located.