# Where does go install the binaries of go get?

Tags: go

I wanted to install ginkgo command and I tried.

```
$ go get github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210616094352-59db8d763f22
go: upgraded github.com/onsi/ginkgo v1.12.1 => v1.16.5
```

But I am not sure where the ginkgo command is installed.

Here is my environment.

```
$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/senthilx/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/senthilx/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/senthilx/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/senthilx/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18.1"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build1077100959=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

The command didn't install ginkgo in my "GOPATH"

```
$ ls
pkg

$ find . -type f -name ginkgo
$
```

Comment: To GOBIN. Print its value with go env.

Comment: `go get` does not install any binaries, it updates `go.mod`. Outside a module it will print `'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install a package with go get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295146/how-can-i-install-a-package-with-go-get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `go get` command is only used for updating module dependencies, it does not install any binaries. The ability to install `main` packages was [deprecated in `go1.17`](https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation). Within a module the `go get` command will show any changes made to the dependencies, as you can see by the output:

```
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210616094352-59db8d763f22
go: upgraded github.com/onsi/ginkgo v1.12.1 => v1.16.5
```

If you try to use `go get` outside of a module it will return the error:

```
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
    'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
    To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
    like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
    For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
    or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.
```

Comment: I had to use `go install -v github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo@v1`

Comment: On my macbook, running go install outside any project installs to /Users/$USER/go/bin